# Multiple If Else statements

Tags: php

I have a if/else statement in PHP which is working, but now after the first if I want to put another if statement. I am now finding the else statement  is applied to the second if statement and not the first.

```
if ($pos > 0 ) {  
    $manuf = $row['manufacturer'];                 
    if ($debug == "true") {
        echo "manuf match found:" . $manuf . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    $manuf = "Unknown";
}
```

How can I correct this?

Update: There is nothing wrong with the code. The original bad formatting led me to believe the code wasn't working. The error was actually caused by a while look above which I didnt include.

Comment: Why do you think else belongs to second if and not first?

Comment: "I am now finding the else statement is applied to the second if statement" No it isn't. The else is applied to the `if ($pos > 0)` condition since that is how you have nested the `{`..`}`.

Comment: Can you format the code?

Comment: @Greg do you see else part belongs to which if after i formatted your code?

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing as @Boann. Additionally, I suggest you change your code formatting, your style is quite "unique" and it's hard to follow the flow this way.

Comment: @almasshaikh: This should have been an answer, not an edit! Now nobody can see the mistake the OP made any more (the strange indention).

Comment: why don't you use `else if` before `else` statement ?

Comment: Because `elseif` is not required. But its seems it was more a formatting problem, see original post, which led OP to believe his if/else logic was executed in the wrong way

Comment: @almas - ye, it looks a lot clearer after the indent fixup. I can't understand why it shouldnt work either. Let me run a few tests again :)

Comment: @Greg either tell us what's the pos value or paste the relevant code where you set it, so we could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Fixed the problem - the indenting was confusing me. There was a while loop above the code which I didnt include - the error was in there!  I really need to fixup my formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. The original bad formatting led me to believe the code wasn't working. The error was actually caused by a while look above which I didnt include.

Its much easier to read after applying the indent correct above.

Also put through my code on http://beta.phpformatter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, use this and let me know.....

```
if ($pos > 0 && $debug =="true" ) {  
    $manuf = $row['manufacturer'];            
    echo "manuf match found:" . $manuf . "<br>";
} else {
    $manuf = "Unknown";
}
```

I am answering from mobile...... So I couldn't format the code well.